# verify that members of c++ objects have constant address during runtime with vector example

Tags: c++, object, constructor, heap-memory

I am trying to convince myself that objects in C++ have constant address during their lifetime. Here is a minimal working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

class Class1
{
    public:

        Class1(unsigned int * pt);

        unsigned int * val_pt;
        
     
};

Class1::Class1(unsigned int * pt)
:
val_pt(pt)
{}


class Class2
{
    public:

      Class2(std::vector<unsigned int> vec_);

      std::vector<unsigned int> vec_of_ints;
      Class1 class1_instance;
  
};
Class2::Class2(std::vector<unsigned int> vec_)
:
vec_of_ints(vec_),
class1_instance(Class1(&vec_of_ints[0]))
{}




int main() {
    
    std::vector<unsigned int> vec_test(10, 2);

    Class2 instance_class2(vec_test);
    Class1 instance_class1 = instance_class2.class1_instance;

    //both addresses are equal
    std::cout<<"Address stored in instance_class1: "<<instance_class1.val_pt<<" ,address of first vec_element of instance_class2: "<<&(instance_class2.vec_of_ints)[0]<<std::endl;

    instance_class2.vec_of_ints.resize(20);
    
    //different addresses now
    std::cout<<"Address stored in instance_class1: "<<instance_class1.val_pt<<" ,address of first vec_element of instance_class2: "<<&(instance_class2.vec_of_ints)[0]<<std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

My Class2 stores a vector of ints and an instance of Class1. Class1 stores the address of the vector of the Class2 instance.

I'd like to get the address of that vector, i.e. the address where the vector is stored on the stack. If my understanding is correct, the resize() function doesn't change that address on the stack but only the content of that address, i.e. where the vector points to in heap.
My overall goal is to show that any modifications of the vector in Class2 are "visible" in the stored pointer of Class1. So if I dereference the pointer in Class1 I will get the same integer value as when accessing the vector itself in Class2. That is because the address of member variables are constant during runtime.

But I guess something is wrong in my code, probably in the constructor where I pass 'vec[0]'. I think this is not the actual address of the vector in the stack but some address on the heap. How do I get the correct address?

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: OK, I have to ask -- what high-level problem are you really trying to solve?  This looks like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  What purpose does it serve to know the address of member variables within a class, at least within your application?  What if the instance of the class loses scope, and you now are pointing to invalid memory?

Comment: Something is wrong in your code.  When a new `Class2` is copy- or move-constructed from an existing `Class2`, it will have an incorrect pointer.

Comment: Yes, exactly I would like to know the address of the member (std::vector<int>). I have a larger application where I have a instance with very large members. So I will only give the address to another instance which has to work with that large members as well. I can make sure that both instances run out of scope one by one, so there are no invalid pointers. But anyway I would to figure out how do get addresses of members.

Comment: @Simon `&vec_of_ints` is the address of the `vector` itself. `&vec_of_ints[0]` is the address of the 1st `unsigned int` element stored in the array inside the `vector`.  If the `vector` is later resized, its array elements *may* change addresses, since the old array would be destroyed and replaced with a new array located elsewhere in memory.

Comment: @Remy Am I right that &vec_of_ints is the address on the stack and &vec_of_ints[0] is some address on the heap (if dynamically allocated)? The latter of course changes then when calling resize()

Comment: @Simon yes, that is correct, in your particular example (it is possible to create a `vector` on the heap, but this example is not doing that).

Comment: `std::vector` is basically a wrapper for `new some_type[some_size]`.  When you do `resize`, what basically happens is the vector will do `new some_type[new_size]`, copy/move the data into that new array, and then delete the old one.

Comment: @Simon You may want to have a look at this video (around that point): https://youtu.be/6OoSgY6NVVk?t=776 It basically explains Nathan Oliver's comment above.

Comment: So to sum up my overall goal: By storing the (stack) address of the vector in Class2 I can be sure that looping over the vector (i) by dereferencing the pointer in Class2 or (ii) using the vector itself in Class1 gives me the same results, simply because the address of the vector is unchanged during runtime? I tried this just for several resize(), pull_back(),... and both approaches lead indeed to same results.

Comment: You are trying to make siomple things very complicated. For example, `Class2` could have a member reference and take a vector by reference in its constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what conclusions you extracted from the comments and responses above.

I just wanted to make sure these were not among them:

1. `The address of a member variable is constant during runtime.`

> If, for example, you have a vector of `Class2` instances, and you
> resize that vector, the address of the `vec_of_ints` member variable
> may change for any of those instances.

2. Having a `Class2` instance in the stack or a pointer to a `Class2` instance in the heap makes a difference.

> The address of the `vec_of_ints` member variable shouldn't change if
> you resize it, no matter the instance of `Class2` is in the stack or
> in the heap.

The example below tests both assertions (https://godbolt.org/z/3TYrnjro8):

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct HoldsIntVector
{
    std::vector<int> v{};
};

int main()
{
    HoldsIntVector stackInstance{};
    auto heapInstance{std::make_unique<HoldsIntVector>()};
    stackInstance.v.push_back(5);
    heapInstance->v.push_back(5);

    auto printStackAndHeapInstances = [&](const auto& text){
        std::cout << std::showbase << std::hex;
        std::cout << &stackInstance << "\t" << &heapInstance << "\t";
        std::cout << &stackInstance.v << "\t" << &heapInstance->v << "\t";
        std::cout << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0') << stackInstance.v.data() << "\t\t";
        std::cout << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0') << heapInstance->v.data() << "\t\t";
        std::cout << text;
        std::cout << "\n";
    };

    std::cout << "stackInstance\theapInstance\tstackInstance.v\theapInstance.v\t&stackInstance.v[0]\t&heapInstance.v[0]\n";
    printStackAndHeapInstances("after initializing stack and heap instances");

    // After resizing both vectors in stack and heap instances
    //
    // Address of v doesn't change neither in stack nor in heap instances
    // Address of v[0] changes in both stack and heap instances
    stackInstance.v.resize(10);
    heapInstance->v.resize(10);
    printStackAndHeapInstances("after resizing both v's");

    std::cout << "\n";

    // Now what happens if we have a vector of HoldsIntVector and we resize it
    //
    // Address of v changes for the first HoldsInVector
    std::vector<HoldsIntVector> hivs{10};
    std::for_each(begin(hivs), end(hivs), [](auto& hiv){hiv.v.push_back(3);});
    std::cout << "&hivs[0].v\n" << &hivs[0].v << "\t" << "after intializing hivs\n";
    hivs.resize(20);
    std::cout << &hivs[0].v << "\t" << "after resizing hivs\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just one question: Why is the object in the second line in main a heapinstance? Can one influence during initialization where a variable is located (stack or heap)?

Comment: @Simon It's created via a smart pointer. `heapInstance` is a unique pointer, sit on the stack, but pointing to a `HoldsIntVector` instance created on the heap (just like if you had done a `new HoldsIntVector{}`)

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing here is ungodly, and needs to stop. Consider this particularly terrible pattern:

```cpp
class DataOwner {
public:

   inline std::vector<uint32_t>& getData() { return data; }
  
private:
   // I am safely tucked away
   std::vector<uint32_t> data;
};

class I_Want_To_Work_On_Data {
public:

   I_Want_To_Work_On_Data(DataOwner* owner) : owner(owner) {}

   void doThing() {

     auto& direct_ref_to_data = owner->getData();

     for(auto& item : direct_ref_to_data) {
        // This is just as fast as your direct pointer :/
     }
   }
  
private:
   DataOwner* owner;
};
```

Returning mutable access to the data is somewhat bad, but it's far safer than the approach you are taking (in a single threaded environment a least).  Performance is no worse than what you are attempting, but it is a lot safer. So what are you optimising this for exactly? How is your approach an improvement over this boring pattern?

Now you could argue that providing mutable access to the std::vector isn't wanted (i.e. don't allow any old code to resize the array), but that can easily be solved without resorting to dirty hacks.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
class DataOwner {
public:

   inline std::vector<uint32_t>::iterator begin()
     { return data.begin(); }
   inline std::vector<uint32_t>::iterator end()
     { return data.end(); }
   inline std::vector<uint32_t>::const_iterator begin() const
     { return data.begin(); }
   inline std::vector<uint32_t>::const_iterator end() const
     { return data.end(); }
  
private:
   // I am safely tucked away
   std::vector<uint32_t> data;
};

class ConstAccess {
public:

   ConstAccess(const DataOwner& owner) : owner(owner) {}

   void doThing() {
     for(const auto& item : owner) {
     }
   }
  
private:
   const DataOwner& owner;
};

class MutableAccess {
public:

   MutableAccess(DataOwner& owner) : owner(owner) {}

   void doThing() {
     for(auto& item : owner) {
     }
   }
  
private:
   DataOwner& owner;
};
```

The performance is the same as with your approach, however this approach as the following advantages:

1. It won't crash in debug builds on this line: `class1_instance(Class1(&vec_of_ints[0]))`, when the vector is empty, and you attempt to dereference NULL to find the address.
2. It won't crash when you attempt to dereference `unsigned int * val_pt;` after you've accidentally resized the array.
3. It won't allow you to accidentally do: `delete [] val_pt`

Comment: `I_Want_To_Work_On_Data `should take and keep a reference to the owner unless it can be null.